# I am trying to ask how to get validation form through js

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, console

I am running this code. Here, I am trying to get error statement after  pressing submit button but I am unable to get any error notification on html web page after typing name in 2 letters(name.length<5 will give error notification). but, I am getting nothing. Can someone look upon this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content ="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title> practice</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1><b>Welcome to the your page.</b></h1>
        <form  action="#" name="myForm" 
        method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
         
         
         
        What is your name?:
        <input id="name" type="text" name="fname"  placeholder="Required" required> 
        <span class ="formerror"></span>
        
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
    </form>
    </body>
    <script>
        function seterror(id,error)
        {
            element= document.getElementById(id);
            element.getElementsByClassName
            ("formerror")[0].innerHTML=error;

        }
        function validateForm(){
            var returnval = true;

            var name = document.forms['myform']["fname"].value;
            if(name.length<5)
            {seterror("fname","length of name is too short");
            returnval = false;}

          //console.log('name sf');
          //return false;
          return returnval;
        }

    </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to use the `minLength` [(1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/minlength) attribute on the input:

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content ="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title> practice</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1><b>Welcome to the your page.</b></h1>
        <form  action="#" name="myForm" 
        method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
         
         
         
        What is your name?:
        <input id="name" type="text" name="fname"  placeholder="Required" required minLength="5"> 
        <span class ="formerror"></span>
        
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
    </form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a problem in your `seterror` function, but the error can't reach the console because your form will always be submitted. No matter what. So, to see what's happening, you should prevent default behaviour:

```js
onsubmit="event.preventDefault();return validateForm()"
```

Then you will get an error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fname')`.

```js
// 'myform' should be 'myForm'
document.forms['myform']
```

Your mistake #2: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getElementsByClassName')`.

```js
// 'element' should be 'document'
element.getElementsByClassName("formerror")[0].innerHTML = error;
```

**Full working code:**

```js
function seterror(id, error) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("formerror")[0].innerHTML = error;
}

function validateForm() {
    var returnval = true;

    var name = document.forms['myForm']["fname"].value;
    if (name.length < 5) {
        seterror("fname", "length of name is too short");
        returnval = false;
    }

    return returnval;
}
```

**Next steps**

Don't use inline event handlers, they are harder to use. Instead you should handle events in modern way with `.addEventListener()`.